# How to send/recieve data to/from bean function using JSF Richfaces AJAX?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, xhtml, richfaces

I'm trying to get some code working in an XHTML/JSF/Spring application through which I send an ID to a bean function and expect a string in return. I haven't found an understandable tutorial on this nor any answered question here on SO.

XHTML:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="inputId" value="#{npBean.idString}"/>
    <a4j:commandButton value="get def" render="out">        
        <f:param value="#{npBean.idString}" name="id" />    
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{npBean.definition}"/>
    </a4j:commandButton>

    <a4j:outputPanel id="out">
        <h:outputText id="outputId" value="#{npBean.def}" 
                                        rendered="#{not empty npBean.def}"/>
    </a4j:outputPanel>

</h:form>
```

Java:

```
public String getDefinition(int id)
{
    def = this.getXService().getXData(id).getDefinition(); 
    return def;
}
```

All values shown have their getters and setters in the bean.

Comment: Which Rich-faces version are you using ?

Comment: 4.2.0Final according to the pom.xml

Comment: If it helps, I don't have this particular xhtml defined anywhere, however the bean and the service are properly in use elsewhere.

Comment: Note that you're using `#{npBean.definition}` where you don't have that attribute. An attribute can be accessed by its getter: `public <type> getXxx()` (no args here). Instead, you have a `getDefinition(int)` method that you're using as a getter (when is not).

Comment: One more note, your getters must be **plain** getters, this means they must not contain any business logic (same for setters).

Comment: Ah, thanks. How do I get around this, though? I need to call a service to get the data I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we basically do:

1. Map the `value` of the `<h:inputText>` component to a property (with getter/setter) in the managed-bean (which is called `myBean`)
2. By using the `reRender` attribute of the `<a4j:commandButton>` component, we point which component on the page to be re-rendered (refreshed) when the button is clicked.
3. When clicking on the button, the `invokeService()` method from the managedBean is executed and it updates the other property of the managedBean.
4. In the `<h:panelGroup>` below, we have several `<h:outputText>` components and with the `rendered` attribute we specify when a component has to be displayed on the page.
5. Exploring the managed-bean, the only thing that is required, are the accessors for the property, which holds the result from the service invoke.

Here's the *.xhtml sample:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

    <a4j:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputText value="String value:" />
            <h:inputText value="#{myBean.value}" />
            <a4j:commandButton value="Click" reRender="out">
                <a4j:actionListener listener="#{myBean.invokeService}" />
            </a4j:comandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </a4j:form>
    <rich:spacer height="7"/>
    <br />
    <h:panelGroup id="out">
        <h:outputText value="Service returned: " rendered="#{not empty myBean.result}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{myBean.result}" />
    </h:panelGroup>

</ui:composition>
```

Managed-bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean")
@SessionScoped //for example
public class MyBean {
   private String value;

   private String result;

   public String getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public String getResult() {
      return result;
   }

   public void invokeService(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
      this.result = "Hello, " + value + "!";
   }
}
```

As @Luiggi mentioned, the accessor methods **MUST** meet the following conventions (if we assume you have a `private <some-type> property;` in the managed-bean.)

```
 public <some-type> getProperty { 
     return property; 
 }

 public void setProperty(<some-type> property) {
     this.property = property:
 }
```

In order to learn how the `RichFaces` components work, combined with good code examples, I suggest you open [this](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/) address and play around with the components.

Comment: Indeed, if you know how to work with plain JSF `<h:commandButton>`, you will understand how RichFaces `<a4j:commandbutton>` works... Just to let you know, this won't solve OP's problem. Check my comment on the question.

Comment: How about retrieving the value with the ID I provide in the input field? I need to call a service with the ID provided so I get the data I need, that's where my problem is.

Comment: I'll get back to you guys tomorrow, thanks for the quick answer though!

Comment: Almost all this is covered in StackOverflow JSF wiki for plain JSF... Also, you forgot something very important: define the scope of the managed bean. Your actual bean is `@NoneScoped`.

Comment: Is there perhaps an error in the code? I'm getting a 500 error from the xhtml and I'm not quite sure what it could be, as the logs aren't being very descriptive about it.

Comment: Found it, apparently the stack seems to be disagreeing with a4j:form. unbelievable.

Comment: Worked perfectly when I got it running. The a4j:commandButton closing tag in the answer is missing an m, though; you might want to correct it for future readers. Thanks!